# How to customize quick form in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
Recipes= new Mongo.Collection('recipes');

Ingredient = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    amount: {
        type: String
    }
}); 

RecipeSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name"
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        label: "Description"
    },
    ingredients: {
        type: [Ingredient]
    },
    inMenu: {
        type: Boolean,
        defaultValue: false,
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        label: "Author",
        autoValue: function(){
            return this.userId
        },
        autoform:{
            type:"hidden"
        }
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Created At",
        autoValue: function(){
            return new Date()
        },
        autoform: {
            type:"hidden"
        }
    }
})
```

How to customize this form into two columns. Two columns should have the input types and how to use bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class field to each column like:

```
author: {
        type: String,
        label: "Author",
        autoValue: function(){
            return this.userId
        },
        autoform:{
            type:"hidden"
        },
        class: 'class-name-here'
    }
```